# Is there a way to programmatically sort Linear Layouts in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

I have a note-taking app for Android, where a `LinearLayout` "notecard" is inflated for each saved note the user has. The parent of these is a `LinearLayout` inside a `ScrollLayout` (this seemed to be the only way I could get it to work). These cards are comprised of a title, body, location tag, and creation time.

I'm wondering if there is a way to build a method that looks at the location, date, or title and sort the layouts in order?

I've been looking at [List Views](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview#java) to see if that is a better parent, but I still can't tell if I would be able to sort the layouts in a `ListView`.

Comment: I would think that `RecyclerView` containing `CardView` would be a better choice.

Comment: And then you could [use `SortedList`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/SortedList) for maintaining your sorted order and updating the `RecyclerView` along the way. See [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.13/RecyclerView/SortedList) for more. Having a collection of `LinearLayout` containers in a `ScrollLayout` is not a particularly good choice for an arbitrary number of notes.

Comment: you don't sort the *layouts*, rather you sort the *data* and rearrange your UI accordingly. Just do a quick research how to present data using a `RecyclerView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using a RecyclerView. You'll need to set up an Adapter for it, but it's easier to manage multiple items (you can reorder them, add swipe or hold actions, etc). You can also sort items with something like a TreeSet.

You'll probably want a data class for your notes, so something like this:

```
class NoteData implements Comparable {
    public String title;
    public String text;
    public long timeInMs;
    //etc

    @Override
    public int compareTo(NoteData other) {
        return title.compareTo(other.title);
    }

}
```

Then, in your RecyclerView Adapter, you can have a TreeSet of NoteData objects. TreeSet automatically orders your items for you, using the Comparable interface, if available (that's why I implemented it above). TreeSet sorts in ascending order by default, but you can pass `Collections.reverseOrder()` to the TreeSet constructor to make it descending.

In my example, I've sorted by title. You can change which variable you compare before compiling, but what I've done doesn't support dynamic ordering. For that, you'll want to do some Googling for examples of how to dynamically sort lists (you should use an ArrayList or Set instead of a TreeSet for this), or of libraries that can do it for you.

[Google's RecyclerView tutorial](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview)
[Another tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidRecyclerView/article.html)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! I'll definitely switch over to a RecyclerView.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the LayoutInflater. Let's say your example XML is in a file custom_layout.xml:

LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null, false);

LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.myLayout);
linear.addView(layout);

**look at Droid:** How to reorder a linearlayouts contents programmatically? and Get all child views inside LinearLayout at once